# Qt: intercept keyboard events during drag-n-drop

Tags: c++, linux, qt, drag-and-drop, keyboard

While performing a drag-n-drop operation, I want to display some extra hints in the status bar on the expected effect of a specific drop action.
To this end, I have overriden dragMoveEvent(), which works perfectly for mouse move events.

However, keyboard signals are evaluated somewhere internally in Qt only (to switch the proposed drop action), but are not exposed during a running drag-n-drop action.

I tried overriding mousePress/ReleaseEvent(), event(), and installing an eventFilter().

Comment: Do you need to know about all keyboard events or just modifiers?  If it's just the modifiers then QDragMoveEvent has a `keyboardModifiers` member.

Comment: Additionally, you can create your own event filter which "listens" for keyboard events: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do: please provide a usage scenario with a complete set of actions performed by the user and the behavior your application should have in reaction to the actions.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a regression from Qt4 to Qt5: While Qt4 triggers QDragMoveEvents, both when moving mouse and pressing modifier keys, Qt5 only issues those events when mouse moves. Hence, I cannot notice changes of modifiers in Qt5, when the mouse does not move. Hence, the solution proposed by @G.M. works in Qt4 but not Qt5.

Comment: I tried the eventFilter() suggested by @AlexSpataru, doesn't work either in Qt5.